# contact structure on 3 manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

every orientable closed 3-manifold admits a contact structure. how we can construct this contact structure? if the manifold is prime what will happen?

Comment: In fact , recently, all contact 3-manifolds have been classified by

1)Lens spaces
2)Torus bundles
3)Circle bundles
4)$S^3$,$ S^2 \times S^1$

Comment: for instance for contact structure on Circle bundle see this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.4948

Comment: Also for finding contact structure of Lens spaces see paper of 
John Etnyre entitled Tight Contact Structures on Lens Spaces 

Comment: Also you can fully study the paper of HANSJÖRG GEIGES for CONTACT STRUCTURES ON TORUS BUNDLES, which published in Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society

Comment: But it would be a good question, if you think about finding  generalized contact structure  concerning your problem, 

Comment: Your question lacks motivation and background. In particular, what did you read already? Recall that it is expected you did your "homework" first, which here would be bibliography.

Comment:  it was my first experience to working on this website.


Comment: If you just want to construct one contact structure, take a Dehn-surgery description of the 3-manifold as surgery on a link in $S^3$ (for each connected component), make the link transverse to the standard contact structure on $S^3$, and add an "overtwisted torus" along each link component. Then take out part of this overtwisted torus as you perform the surgery. This will generally produce an overtwisted contact structure on the manifold.

Comment: @Arash: welcome here then; you can find relevant information on "how to ask" by following the corresponding link on top of the pages.

Comment: Lutz and Martinet also proved the existence of contact structures on 3-manifolds using the existence of triangulations -- rather then then the existence of Dehn surgery presentations -- and some ideas from foliation theory.  The ones described in the proof are all overtwisted although that terminology didn't exist at the time.  For a sketch see Honda's notes http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~khonda/math599/notes.pdf section 5.3.